# Crystal Report (8.5) on win7/windows 2008 64 bit system

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Report (8.5) is not working on win7/windows 2008 64 bit system

My application is a VB application and I am using Crystal report 8.5. It is working fine on 32 bit system and 64 bit system of Windows 2003 server. When I run the same application either on win7 64 bit or on 2008 64 bit, report does not open.
I am using vb script to access the database.

Part of the code written in the VB script file is as follows:

```
Dim objrsRecordSet                 'As RecordSet
Dim strSQL                         'As String

'**** Open Database Connection using the parameters passed from the main program
Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=" & mstrServer & ";uid=" & mstrUserName _
                                & ";pwd=" & mstrPassword & ";Database=" & mstrDatabase & ";"

dbConnection.Open
dbConnection.CommandTimeout = 200

dbConnection.Properties("Enable Fastload").Value = True
```

When I run my application in debug mode it is working fine on windows 7 also. But when I run the application through the set up by consuming the .dll of crystal report then it is not working, in this case report is not opening.

Please help me out with this issue, i will appreciate for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I generally put all Crystal 8.5 deployment DLLs under %systemroot%\crystal and put it on the system PATH. That resolved me 95% of most common deploy related problems.

Answer (score -1):

Also answered here: [Installing Crystal Reports 8.5 on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1245887/installing-crystal-reports-8-5-on-windows-7)

This version of Crystal is simply too old for newer operating systems... I can confirm that v10 and up works fine on Windows 7.